# Those differential operators that are bounded.

Tags: operator-theory

Differential operators are known as unbounded operators, but there always are some exceptions.
Does anyone know an example of a differential operator on appropriate Sobolev spaces that is not unbounded?

thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example:
$A:H_0^1(I) \to L^2(I)$

$Af=df/dx$

but be careful $A:L^2(I) \to L^2(I)$, with the same definition, is not bounded.